# An example of a closed set through sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm here to ask you for a concrete example about how to show a set is closed through the definition of convergent sequences.

I mean, I know that

> A set $S$ is closed if for any convergent sequence belonging to $S$, that sequence converges to an element in $S$

So I'm asking you for a concrete example, with a real succession. I searched for it over here but I found nothing.

Thank you

Comment: This is not true in general unless the space $S$ has other properties: first countable for example. Otherwise sequences are not enough to describe closure (nets and/or filters will do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the definition to show that a certain set $S$ is not closed. You just need to present a sequence of elements in $S$ that converges to a point $x \notin S$. For instance, if you take the set $]0,1]$ and the sequence $u_n = \frac 1n$, you can show that $]0,1]$ is not closed.

Comment: Thak you too! Great!

Answer (score 2):

Take for instance, the set $[-1,1]$. If $(u_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is any convergent sequence of elements of $[-1,1]$, then

- since, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $u_n\leqslant1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n\leqslant1$;
- since, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $u_n\geqslant-1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n\geqslant-1$.

So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n\in[-1,1]$. Therefore, $[-1,1]$ is a closed set.

Comment: Oh, this is enlightening. Thank you so much!!